# Username and password fields are changing after RSA encryption in login.jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, authentication, encryption, struts

I have encrypted the username and password field using JSEncrypt in `login.jsp` page and then I set the encrypted username/password in these form username/password fields so that these fields are passed to backend server which is in struts

`document.getElementById("username").value=encryptedUserName;`
`document.getElementById("password").value=encryptedPassword;`

I am able to decrypt the fields at server side and perform authentication.

But due to below code

`document.getElementById("username").value=encryptedUserName;`
`document.getElementById("password").value=encryptedPassword;`

the actual username/password fields are updated with the encrypted username/password and this is visible to user.

Is there any way such that i can send the encrypted username/password to server but the actual username/password fields value will not be changed in the login form itself ?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: ... Don't set them into the user-visible fields? Maybe... hidden fields? Or... maybe use HTTPS and don't re-invent something that's already in place?

Comment: even in https , username/password are visible in the developer options in the the form data, thats why i encrypted them before sending to server

Comment: ... this makes no sense. The user typed them in—they already know. The code that encrypts them would also be visible in the Dev console too—*everything* is. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: if password filed is visible in form data under network than it may be captured by someone in transit. So better to encypt it before sending. Also i am using RSA encryption which means to decrypt the encrypted password, it requires private key which i only have access to. So it make sense ...

Comment: This is what https is for.

Comment: In https too, password is visible under form data in the network mode